# We need to develop our own SMS Gateway in India using windows and .NET, How should we start?

Tags: sms, sms-gateway

We need to develop our own SMS Gateway in India using windows and .NET, How should we start ?
What is the procedure ? what technical components we will need ? What kind of hardware we shall use ?
Our SMS load monthly shall be 1 million initially or may be less than that.

Please suggest.

Comment: Please also suggest solutions other than windows platform as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you need to connent to your mobile provider's SMSC over SMPP protocol?
Do you need to support SMPP, some custom HTTP, SOAP, etc as client interfaces?
If you answer yes on both then this might interest you http://www.powermemobile.com/PressRelease-OpenAlley

SMPP Server - https://github.com/PowerMeMobile/funnel_mini

ONEAPI Interface (SendSMS only) - https://github.com/PowerMeMobile/oneapi_srv

Middleware - https://github.com/PowerMeMobile/kelly

SMPP Client - https://github.com/PowerMeMobile/just_mini

Written in Erlang, now in production